# How do i play video in mobile using intex xdk?

Tags: intel-xdk

I need to play a video in android/ios, dont know what plugin to add and how do all stuffs.
so for i refereed this below link
 [link](http://qnimate.com/playing-videos-in-intel-xdk-app/#prettyPhoto)

But i could not find the cordova plugin - **player** as mention in the link.

Any other ideas or plugins are appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

At last, i just fixed my problem by using **cordova plugin**,tested in android it works fine,it creates a video player(as well as we can create audio player) itself instead of using native player. Here is the full source and reference from github [link](https://github.com/rajsibi7/cordova-plugin-streaming-media).